# Using long press to toggle

Tags: ios, swift, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I would like to use a long press gesture to toggle an .isHidden property of a tableView.  My code (below) makes the tableView appear upon the first long press but does not hide it upon the second long press.

```
let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
var hideTableView = true
@IBAction func longPress(_ sender: Any) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        hideTableView = !hideTableView
    }

    if hideTableView {
        tableView.isHidden = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if !hideTableView {
        tableView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to move all of the code to inside the `if recognizer.state == .began {` block.

Next, get rid of the `hideTableView` property. Simply toggle the `isHidden` property of the table view. Then reload is it's `false` after being toggled.

```
@IBACTION func longPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        tableView.isHidden = !tableView.isHidden
        if !tableView.isHidden {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.  Very elegant.  As a further improvement I replaced recognizer.state with sender.state in your second line and forwent constructing a UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to make that change when I updated the parameter. Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been solved by accepting the answer (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).